# Passing Params from PHP to Powershell exec

Tags: php, powershell, parameter-passing

I am attempting to write a *PHP script* that will allow for me to select a few files to download from a predetermined location. I'd like my script to pass an array to a *Powershell script* that id written earlier and have my *Powershell script* handle the downloading (basically the php file just needs to tell the *powershell* file what needs to be downloaded).
I've looked at a few options, and it seems that `exec` is the command I should use for this (as I do not care about command line output I shouldnt need `shell_exec`).

So far I've turned `OFF` safe mode to allow me to use this command. I should also note that the *php* file will be run from a server, however the *powershell* files are located on a local machine.

A snippet of the code so far to handle the param passing looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
{
    $choosePlugin = $_POST['wpPlugin'];
    $chooseTheme = $_POST['wpTheme'];

    if(isset($_POST['wpTheme'])) 
    {
        echo("<p>You selected: $chooseTheme</p>\n");
        exec('powershell.exe C:\Wordpress Setup\setupThemes.ps1 $chooseTheme');

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("<p>You did not select a theme</p>\n");
    }
```

I am a bit confused as to what I should put inside the `exec`.  When I run the above code there are no errors however nothing happens. I am a bit new to this so I apologize if more information is required. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do:

```
echo exec('powershell.exe C:\\Wordpress Setup\\setupThemes.ps1 $chooseTheme');
```

to see the results of powershell.exe (remember the double \), also make sure to put the absolute path to the exe file:

```
 echo exec('c:\\PATH_TO_POWERSHELL.EXE\\powershell.exe C:\\Wordpress Setup\\setupThemes.ps1 $chooseTheme');
```

Comment: Ive changed my code to:
echo      exec('C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe "C:\\Wordpress Setup\\setupThemes.ps1" $chooseTheme 2>&1');
And I receive the error: sh: C:WindowsSystem32WindowsPowerShellv1.0powershell.exe: command not found
By command not found I assume this means the server is trying to run the script but does not have access to my local machine?  Sorry again not sure the solution for this.

Comment: check if the apache (or IIS) user have read permissions in windows folder

Comment: yes, it seems is permission problem, see this comment in the php.net page: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php#101837 (about windows and exec)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the contents of the variable you should use double quotes to actually expand it, I guess. Furthermore you should quote the script name because the path contains spaces:

```
exec("powershell.exe \"C:\Wordpress Setup\setupThemes.ps1\" $chooseTheme");
```