# Powershell: read host from html

Tags: php, powershell

I've got a `.ps1` script (which looks after quotas) which is called by an html/php page.Is it possible to get a read host when a user call my script (in order to provide a specific user)?

I simply tried to put a read-host in my .ps1 script `($user= read-host "Please, specify a user")` but i doesnt work...

*For your information, here is the html page:*

```
<?php

shell_exec('powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -command "& {"./quotas-disk-d.ps1"; exit $err}"');
header ("Refresh: 0;URL=./quot.html");

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell command to ask for input is almost right, but should include -Prompt:

```
$user = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter a username"
```

You can then use `$user` just like any other variable.

---

I believe your main problem here, is that you need something besides PowerShell asking for the input. If your server is running the PowerShell script, then the user is not directly accessing the PowerShell console and will not get the prompt.

[It is possible,](http://theboywonder.co.uk/2012/07/29/executing-powershell-using-php-and-iis/) from a pure server approach.

I believe what you want to do (I am not a PHP guy) is prompt for the username in your php, and then pass that in to the powershell script, [as detailed here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617938/passing-params-from-php-to-powershell-exec)

```
shell_exec('powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -command 
"& {"./quotas-disk-d.ps1 $userNameFromPhp"; exit $err}"');
```

Comment: Ok, but it does not solve the problem. I still have nothing asking me for entering username...

Comment: @MatStack I added some info, but now I have more questions. Is this all server side, or is the .ps1 client side? is the PowerShell console exposed to the end user at all? Or is it a web page that then calls the script on the web server?

Comment: It is all server side, files are stored on the local disk c:\. I use wamp server on my local machine to test, so the server is also the client. The web page calls the .ps1

Comment: @MatStack hopefully that is it, otherwise I added the php tag, maybe a php guy can do better.